# Long running requests in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I was wondering if there is any good practice how to utilize long-running requests in nodejs?
I am using Express.js and have been wondering if there is any way to, I don't know, move one of express requests to the different instance of node or something?

The reason why I am wondering is that if strongly uses a CPU, blocking at the same time event loop in node. The main problem is that firstly, I am fetching some data, then calculating and inserting missing data into DB, then fetching other data depends on the result, and then calculating again and updating other stuff in DB.

I haven't noticed this problem as I was the only one using this request so far. But now I am testing it with other users and if few of them use this request, the whole application freeze for a few seconds. And on my monitoring tools I see a huge CPU usage (100%-200% lol)

So I have tried clustering but it seems, it does not work. I have used pm2 and ran app on all cores of my CPU. Because of complexicity of my alghoritm I tried to move several functions to worker threads but it looks like these threads would be used very, very often and I am afraid of crashing the whole node instance.

I have no clue, which solution would be the best and don't know if are there any good tools for Express, which would help me offload/utilize these requests? I have not diveed in partitioning yet, but it looks like this may work. Has anyone used this for the larger projects and knows if this could be the solution to distribute one request into several ticks?

What about the job queue like Bull or Kue? Would be this a good idea to push these tasks into a queue? I have never used such tools and I am asking, as I have no idea if this would make any sense.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

in case you have data present - You can sent data to user using incoming HTTP request.
but if you don't found any data you can send empty response in HTTP request.

And you need to do calculating and inserting missing data using queue service. [bee-queue](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue) is nice one.

Use redis with bee-queue to make background jobs faster.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this one. :)